# How to make sql query from an Array in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

Please tell me how can we make sql query from array is it possible?

```
This is my code       
$myString = "Food,FastFood,Chinese";
        $myArray = explode(',', $myString);
        print_r($myArray);
```

This is output of above code:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Food
    [1] => FastFood
    [2] => Chinese
)
```

My question is how can I make sql query from this array in php like

```
$sql="Select * from table where FoodCategories=$Food OR FoodCategories=$FastFood OR FoodCategories=$Chinese ";
```

Please help me out.

Comment: instead why can't you use IN?

Comment: `Select * from table where FoodCategories IN ($myString)` will produce the same result

Comment: I am new to php I don't know IN?

Comment: `IN` is not related to php. It is sql. And `IN` is the most basic concept of sql newbie

Comment: Could you give me one example please? How can I done this problem?

Comment: @MajidAli IN is keyword in SQL, you can provide comma separated values to check in a set

Comment: Thanks bro but how can I get the values from this array like value1, value 2 mean i need value to give into IN set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$string="Food,FastFood,Chinese";
$array=explode(',', $string);
$array = implode("','",$array);
echo $query="Select * from table where FoodCategories IN ('".$array."')";
```

Comment: why are you imploding again?

Answer (score -1):

You could create an SQL Statement with an IN-Condition. Check the official doc from MySQL - [MySQL IN-Condition](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp).

**EDIT**:
This would be your new query:

```
// you first have to implode your array and add quotes for each array item
$string = "'" . implode("','", $myArray) . "'";
// now you can create your new query
$sql = "Select * from table where FoodCategories IN ($string)";
```

Comment: __Wrong__, there're no qutes around value in string!

Comment: @u_mulder right thanks... sorry for that - code is now edited.

Comment: why are you imploding again?

Comment: Because I'd like to have quotes around each value in $myArray. This code results in following SQL statement: `Select * from table where FoodCategories IN ('Food', 'FastFood', 'Chinese')`

Comment: @BenjaminBur you can use str_replace. No need to implode again.

Comment: @ÖzgürCanKaragöz this is an example of how to solve the problem with the given array. Of course you could also do that by `str_replace` without `implode` and `explode` - but I can't see the big benefit in this case here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `in`

Try the following

```
$data = "'".implode("','",$myString)."'";
sql="Select * from table where FoodCategories in($data)";
```

Comment: __Wrong__, there're no qutes around value in string!

Comment: @u_mulder Thank you . Edited the answer

Comment: why are you imploding again?

Answer (score -1):

Try this with easy way :)

```
$myString =array("Food","FastFood","Chinese");
// make them together with ', '
$userStr = implode("', '", $myString );
$query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE FoodCategories in ('$userStr')";
```